# How to calculate total amount of items

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here i want to calculate the total price of items. Here i import all values from express session. But i couldn't find the way to get total amount

```html
<div class="cart-list">
   <!-- Single Cart Item -->
   <div class="single-cart-item">
      <% if(typeof items.cart!=="undefined"){ %>
      <% items.cart.forEach(function(file) { %>
      <a href="#" id="displayImage" class="product-image">
         <img src="/image/<%= file.items %>" class="cart-thumb" 
            alt="">
         <div class="cart-item-desc">
            <span class="product-remove"><i class="fa fa-close" 
               aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <span class="badge"><%= file.brand %></span>
            <h6><%= file.name %></h6>
            <p class="price">LKR. <%= file.price %></p>
            <p class="color"><%= file.color %></p>
            <%  var amount = 0;
               amount += parseInt(file.price); %>
            <p class="total"><%= amount %></p>
         </div>
      </a>
      <% }); } %>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You probably want to declare `var amount = 0` once at the top.

Comment: You might want to perform the calculation separately, outside of your HTML rendering. It's called "separation of concerns" and mixing calculation logic with HTML makes both harder to read.

Comment: this is side question but why is the displaying total price tag inside iteration?

Comment: #alex ya it worked ! Thank you for your comments #dai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var total = items.cart.reduce((acc, item) => { return acc + item.price }, 0)
```

Use `array.reduce` to add up the values

Or do what @Dai said in your comments, add it up outside of your rendering and pass it in as a variable.

Comment: It's worked ! But as i mentioned above isn't my original code. I have separate portion to display total amount. The problem is when i need get a price of items i should want call a loop to implement those function according to your formula. Thereby it will printed multiple times when i display them. So how to get rid of this problem.

Comment: <h2>Summary</h2>
                 <ul class="summary-table">

                     <li><span>subtotal:</span> <span></span></li>
                     <li><span>delivery:</span> <span style="color:green">Free</span></li>
                     <!-- <li><span>discount:</span> <span>-15%</span></li> -->
                     <li><span>total:</span> <span></span></li>
                 </ul>